# Performance Tester for mongodb and mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, mongodb, testing

i am fairly new to MongoDB and i have created MySQL and MongoDB databases with 15000 records and 7 different tables using Linux terminal. Now I am trying to test their performance by applying CRUD and am not sure where to begin so if you could point me to the right direction it will be great. I have looked at benchmark and Jmeter but I am not sure how they really work.

thanks

Comment: It depends for what purpose your gonna use it for. Without any additional example its hard to give an opion

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: i know its not typical programming question but i didnt know where else to ask and thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Noob i am trying to test the response time like how long it takes to respond when executing one query such as select * from customers.

Answer (score 0):

> YCSB is used by some organizations as part of their performance testing for several different database technologies. YCSB is fairly basic and probably does not tell you everything you need to know about the performance of your application. However, it is fairly popular and understood by users of MongoDB and other systems. In this post we’ll compare YCSB results for MongoDB 2.6 and 3.0.

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-testing-mongodb-30-part-1-throughput-improvements-measured-ycsb